# XStream conversion exception on a xml date and time string

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-serialization, xstream

The XML i trying to convert looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTrafiklage>
  <Trafiklage>
    <Utgangsdatum xmlns="">2011-10-14T00:00:00+02:00</Utgangsdatum>
  </Trafiklage>
  <Trafiklage>
    <Utgangsdatum xmlns="">2011-10-15T00:00:00+02:00</Utgangsdatum>
  </Trafiklage>
  <Trafiklage>
    <Utgangsdatum xmlns="">2011-10-16T00:00:00+02:00</Utgangsdatum>
  </Trafiklage>
</ArrayOfTrafiklage>
```

My code to convert looks like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

xstream.alias("ArrayOfTrafiklage", Trafiklagen.class);
xstream.alias("Trafiklage", StationInfoModel.class);

Trafiklagen trafiklagen = (Trafiklagen) xstream
        .fromXML(result);
```

The StationInfoModel.java looks like:

```
public class StationInfoModel 
{
    private Date Utgangsdatum;
}
```

And i getting this Exception when it running the fromXML command:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Utgangsdatum : Utgangsdatum
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Utgangsdatum
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : Utgangsdatum
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /ArrayOfTrafiklage/Trafiklage/Utgangsdatum
class[1]            : org.rickardp.trainstatus.Models.Trafiklagen
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 0.0
-------------------------------
```

Do someone has any idea what i doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick glance, but you may need to alias "Utgangsdatum," or try it fully qualified in the XML. XStream probably can't tell what a "Utgangsdatum" is because there is no alias, and it's not a full class name in the XML.

Comment: Charlie Collins: Why should i need a class for Utgangsdatum, its should match it with the Date object in StationInfoModel what i can understand in the documentation of XStream

Comment: Yeah, sorry, quick glance was a bad idea, as I didn't notice that even though the exception is that that  name can't be resolved, it's not a class, just a date. Upper case naming confused me.

Comment: I've got a problem that looks very similar. I'm already setting aliases all over the place, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
private static SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z");
```

```
frmt.format(date)
```